# How to read cookbook file at recipe compilation time?

Tags: chef-infra

This kind of thing is commonly seen in Chef recipes:

```
%w{foo bar baz}.each do |x|
  file "#{x}" do
    content "whatever"
  end
end
```

But I want to read the items to loop over from a file which is kept with the cookbook, for example:

```
File.open('files/default/blah.txt').each do |x|
  file "#{x}" do
    content "whatever"
  end
end
```

This works if I give the full path to `blah.txt` where chef-client happens to cache it, but it's not portable.  It doesn't work if I write it like in the example, "hoping" that the current directory is the root of the cookbook.  Is there a way to obtain the cookbook root directory as the recipes are compiled?

Comment: Why do you want to use a cookbook_file for this? Seems like it should be a data_bag or node attribute.

Comment: I don't want to use `cookbook_file`.  I want to use a file contained in my cookbook.  I know I could use attributes or data bags, but in this case, using a specially crafted file would be better for some reasons.

Comment: The only cause for this I see is that you need this file on target machine too. But in this case, you should put your list (foo bar baz) into data_bag or attributes and then generate this file from them using template.

Comment: I'd also say attributes are right for this..

Comment: But the Chef Server will ignore some files, so you'll need to use a cookbook_file. Files are lazily downloaded as needed, so even if you put it in your cookbook, the Chef Server won't download it to the node unless it's used in a resource (Chef 11)

Comment: @PeterEisentraut would another way to phrase your question be "How can I read+parse a custom formatted file into attributes or a data bag at compile time?"

Comment: Have you considered simply installing the file into some temp space on the node, then reading it?  I agree with prior comments - data bags and attributes are designed for this use case.

Answer (score 4):

In Chef 11, you can get clever and use Dir globbing to achieve your desired behavior:

1. Disable lazy loading of assets. With lazy asset loading enabled, Chef will fetch assets (like cookbook files, templates, etc) as they are requested during the Chef Client run. In your use case, you need those assets to exist on the server **before** the recipe execution starts. Add the following to the `client.rb`:

   ```
   no_lazy_load true
   ```
2. Find the path to the cookbook's cache on disk. This is a little bit of magic and experimentation, but:

   ```
   "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/cookbooks/NAME"
   ```
3. Get the correct file:

   ```
   path = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/cookbooks/NAME/files/default/blah.txt"
   File.readlines(path).each do |line|
     name = line.strip

     # Whatever chef execution here...
   end
   ```

You might also want to look at `Cookbook.preferred_filename_on_disk` if you care about using the File Specificity handlers.

Comment: I would like to add that this solution works for Berkshelf-based cookbooks/workflows, but not for Policyfile-based cookbooks/workflows.  With Policyfiles, cookbook assets get loaded to the path `#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/cookbook_artifacts/${name}-${unique_identifier}`, which makes it much trickier to locate the precise path to a particular cookbook's assets unless you happen to be able to dynamically resolve `unique_identifier`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, for those who don't need the file content until converge time, but one that does not require any client.rb modifications, is to use cookbook_file to read the resource into your file_cache_path and then lazy load it.  Here is an example where I read in a groovy script to be embedded into an xml template.

```
script_file = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/bootstrap-machine.groovy"
cookbook_file script_file do
    source 'bootstrap-machine.groovy'
end

config_xml = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/bootstrap-machine-job.xml"

template config_xml do
    source 'bootstrap-machine-job.xml.erb'
    variables(lazy {{
        :groovy_script => File.open(script_file).read
    }})
end
```

Comment: This is a good general solution.  I would also like to add that this method is commonly used "in the wild" - for instance, it's the suggested way of invoking the [`jenkins_job` resource](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins#jenkins_job).

Answer (score 3):

For neatness' sake, I like to use a combination of `File.join()` and 
the "cookbook_name" variable.

```
File.join(
  Chef::Config[:file_cache_path],
  'cookbooks',
  cookbook_name,
  'path/to/blah.txt'
)
```