# Read files in Chef without writing to the node

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to read a file's contents and use it in my ruby code. In this step, I am not trying to do anything on the bootstrapped node. All I want to do is read a JSON file that will reside in cookbook's files folder and read the contents of the file and do something. I just want to use the value coming from JSON in my code itself. The code example is shown below. Any help is appreciated.

**Attributes: default.rb**

```
default["xyz"]["ohs_servers"]=[
  {"hostname"=> "intf301.linux.xyz.com","name" => "INTFIN_OHS_001", "short_name" => "OGS", "port" => "9931"},
  {"hostname"=> "intf302.linux.xyz.com","name" => "INTFIN_OHS_001", "short_name" => "OHS", "port" => "9931"}
]
```

**Machines: machines.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

json = File.read('environment.json')
obj = JSON.parse(json)

number = obj["name"]

x = node["xyz"]["ohs_servers"][number]["hostname"]
```

**JSON file in cookbook's files folder: environment.json**

```
{
  "template_name": "environment_template",
  "number": 0
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?  The node object is already json, why not just put this data into an attributes file?

Comment: I'd say [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006941/how-to-read-cookbook-file-at-recipe-compilation-time) should provide you the path of the `environment.json` on disk. But I'm also not sure what your goal is. We might be able to better help you, when we know that.

Comment: I am trying to reuse the cookbook for different environments. I have different templates(json) files for different environments. I do not want to populate attribute values from the json file. The code I have above is just a simple illustration to make it easy to understand.

Comment: In this case you s old gain having an environment cookbook (empty recipe and an attribute file with your values) and use it in your recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cookbook_file` and then add `run_action(:create)`

```
cookbook_file "myfile.txt" do
   path "somepathyouwantthefilebe/myfile.txt"
   source "myfile.txt"  #the name of the file in files folder of your cookbook"
end.run_action(:create)  # read notes** bellow
```

then you can have some ruby code to read from it
for example

```
File::read("somepathyouwantthefilebe/myfile.txt")
```

** the run action is nessecary since you are combining ruby code and resources in chef-zero

Comment: About the note: not only in chef-zero, it's the way to converge a resource at compile time in any chef run (client, solo or zero).

Answer (score 2):

Even if I don't really get why you don't want to use attributes for this:

What you want is to ensure the cookbook files are in the cache even if there's no resource calling them, the way to go is to configure the `client.rb` on the node with the `no_lazy_load` attribute to `true`

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) about this option:

> `no_lazy_load`    Use to download all cookbook files and templates at the
>   beginning of the chef-client run. Default value: `true`.

I'm unsure if the default value has changed with 12 or on wich version, but I'm quite sure it was false in chef 11 (loading file or template when the provider referencing them is called)

Then you can read your file using

```
File::read("#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/cookbooks/my_cookbook/files/my_file.json")
```

Edit: Just saw the comment of Stephen King, I more or less paraphrased Seth Vargo's answer here :/

Comment: I am using Chef-zero right now. Any idea how I can access the file using Chef-zero?

Comment: Replace file_cache_path by cookbook_path (will work if you have only one dir and not an array)